# In JNI,Blowfish in C++ cannot encrypt/decrypt correctly

Tags: android, c++, encryption

I tried to **migrate** the **Blowfish algorithm** to the **Android Native** which is implement on C++. 
But there are some confusing for me! 
I get **everything OK when ecrypting**, but it **can not** get a **correctly** **decryption**.
Following the code:

I do this in the JNI:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_myview_myndk_LoadNative_e(JNIEnv *env, jobject this_obj,jstring src) {
const string key = "abcfgetq";
vector<char> k(key.begin(), key.end());
Blowfish blowfish(k);

jboolean isCopy;
const char *src_char = env->GetStringUTFChars(src, &isCopy);
LOGI("jchar %s======================",src_char);

const vector<char> src_vector(src_char,src_char+strlen(src_char));

vector<char> encyyption = blowfish.Encrypt(src_vector);
char *en_char = &encyyption[0];
const string en_str(en_char);
string base64_en = base64::encode(en_str);

const char *base64_de_char = base64::decode(base64_en).c_str();
vector<char> decryption = blowfish.Decrypt(vector<char>(base64_de_char,base64_de_char+strlen(base64_de_char)));
char *de_char = &decryption[0];
string de_str(de_char);

//log decryption
LOGI("decryption is %s======================",de_str.c_str());


return env->NewStringUTF(base64_en.c_str());

}
```

I got the results like that:

**Before encryption:**

```
Hello!!How Are You?!//..,,++||**
```

**While encrypted:**

```
8�{}�a�-�@e�ՠ�ϡz�P]#S�/��P(**
```

**After decryption:**

```
Hello!!How Are You?!//..,,++||ԘJi**
```

What's wrong with that? 
I've working at this about two days and I really confused about that! 
If I missed something about you push a right answer, please tell me.

***THANKS FOR YOUR intelligence!***

Comment: The only problem I see here is you assuming there's a zero byte after the decrypted string, in `string de_str(de_char)`.

Comment: you mean I should code like this: `de_char[de_char_len+1]='\0'`?

Comment: And I also need to do the same thing about the en_char.

Comment: @S.Liang Can you share the sample with imports, may be you can answer your own question if its' resolved. I am trying to do the same.